# Best way to synchronize several databases in different computers

Tags: java

I must to do a POS program for college in Java, the problem is that I don't know how to link the different computers to a master computer that handles the changes of the database and sends them to the others PCs .

I've thought the best way is that every computer has their own copy of the database and the changes are made directly on this database and later sends them to the master PC, which return the changes made by others computers.
Too, I could do it using only one database in the master, but I don't know if this are going to respond well when all the computers are working at the same time.

Do you have any alternative? or It'll work fine with whatever of the ways I've thought?

Comment: It depends on whether you're trying to shard or replicate. But easiest would be to just have centralized database.

Comment: store the changes with a time stamp on each computer then sync them in server

Comment: Assuming POS means point of sale, each register having its own database is a more robust solution than a central database.  Purchases are independent, so the register database can update the central database every few minutes, assuming the connection exists.  You don't want to wait until the end of the day because you probably are adjusting inventory based on purchases.